# Google Analytics Reporting API GoalXXCompletions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to hit the GA Reporting API v4 to get "goalXXCompletions"

The goal is numbered 3 in GA UI. However, when I try to hit the API to get;

```
    var goals = Request()
    .select("date","goalCompletionLocation","goal3Completions")
    .from(xyz)
    .during(date, date);
```

it throws an error.

Works perfectly fine when I use goalCompletionsAll, but that's not that I'm trying to pull out.

Using this npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-simple-ga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure what's going on with this npm package, ended up using the raw googleapis and it's working fine.

Good resource;
https://www.multiminds.eu/blog/2018/11/22/google-analytics-reporting-api/